# How to Parse JSON when the object name is a number?

Tags: json, swift

I have been trying to parse the JSON data I get from my browser, however, I've run into a problem. In the browser, when I copy the path of the property: bedrooms, this is the path I get:

- 0.bedrooms

The 0 is the name of the object, and bedrooms is listed under that object as a property. When I try to create a variable with the name 0, Swift does not allow it, and without this variable, I can't match the path.

Here is my code for the different objects in the form of structs:

```
    struct HomeData: Codable{
        let 0: Object0 <--------This line does not work
    }

    struct Object0: Codable{
        let bathrooms: Double
        let bedrooms: Double
        let price: Int
        let rawAdress: String
        let squareFootage: Int
        let propertyType: String
    }
```

Here is the code to parse the JSON:

```
    func parseJSON(homeData: Data){
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do{
                let decodedData = try decoder.decode(HomeData.self, from: homeData)
                print(decodedData.0.bathrooms) <---This line gives an error as well
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
    }
```

How can I parse this data? Any help will be much appreciated!

Also, here is the data. [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPhsw.png)

Comment: Is it really an object with numeric keys and not an array? The former is possible to deal with using `CodingKeys` but the latter is much more common.

Comment: Without seeing the data it is hard to give an exact answer but one way to handle this is to decode it as a dictionary, something like `[Int: Object0].self`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have shown the data in the question. Is it easier for you to answer it now?

Comment: `[Int: Object0]` seems better than coding all the 0, 1, 2, 3, keys... You'd need to name them differently like `let key0: Object0`, etc., and in use custom CodingKeys, with `case key0 = "0"`...

Comment: @hobbs The name of the object is 0. You can take a look at the data picture I have attached. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: @Larme Where do I add the [Int: Object0]? Also, what are custom Coding Keys?

Comment: But wait. JSON keys are String, they can't be Int. Could you print `String(data: homeData, encoding: .utf8)`?

Comment: It didn't print anything

Comment: @RugyCodez that's an array. You can tell by the `[`.

Comment: @hobbs Oh, I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot the root object is an array

```
struct HomeData: Decodable {
    let bathrooms: Double
    let bedrooms: Double
    let price: Int
    let rawAddress: String
    let squareFootage: Int
    let propertyType: String
}

func parseJSON(homeData: Data){
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do{
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode([HomeData].self, from: homeData)
            print(decodedData.first?.bathrooms
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
}
```

Comment: I get this error after trying out your solution. Holy Home[43403:2596005] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(151) Failed to log metrics
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "rawAdress", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"rawAdress\", intValue: nil) (\"rawAdress\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: @JoakimDanielson You're right! Thanks a lot. Also, thank you to vadian for providing the solution.